# Executing code on Visual Studio Debugger exit

Tags: windows, visual-studio, winapi, visual-studio-debugging

I have an external input device that I need to turn off on executable exit.

Is there a way to execute code in C when Visual Studio Debugger exits so I can turn the device off?

Comment: This falls in the "we don't want you to do that" category.  It usually works but you can't get support for it.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/envdte._dispdebuggerevents_event.onenterdesignmode%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks Hans.

Sorry I should have been more specific. It's a C executable that does not use .net.

Comment: You can start any program with the Process class.

Comment: I'm not following @hans. Are you suggesting a .net extension? The only Process class I see is [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process) in System.Diagnostics. I don't think I have access to that without .net dlls?